# If unit testing is so great, why aren't more companies doing it?

Tags: unit-testing

The first real software company that I worked at was all about the unit testing (NUnit). I don't know that we were real sticklers for it back then -- I have no idea what our code coverage was like and I was writing most of the unit tests. Since then I've run into some companies that do lots of testing, but it's chair testing: relies on a person being there, has low repeatibility and low chance of catching bugs. The other attitude is: it was something they wanted to get going with "in the future"; basically when money falls from the sky.

I miss unit testing -- it just makes life easier. But I'm finding that when I look for a new job, unit testing is either something that companies would like to "get going with" in the future or something they don't do at all (uhh, it's been around for a while now!). I'd say that 60-75% of the job reqs I've looked at over the past 2 years have not listed unit testing at all. I can only think of one or two that had unit testing experience as a requirement (for a mid-level developer position).

So the question is, **what's missing**? I think it makes people more productive, but that's only after spending a solid amount of time actually doing it. Aren't there any good studies about the cost savings of unit testing? Is it the type of company I'm looking at?

Edit: even though the title is a bit devils-advocate, I consider myself a unit testing proponent.

Comment: What kind of domain are you working in? I've always encountered unit tests, of varying completeness, wherever I've worked. But my experience lies in medical and industrial imaging, so that might be why...

Comment: Yeah, I suspect you're right. My domain is usually line-of-business apps; no one's life in the balance. But sometimes some billing in the balance, and that can get costly.

Comment: Chair testing: person sits in chair, drives application, reports bugs.

Comment: @Darknight should have 50k upvotes for his honesty. C'mon old heads, get hip to today's time. Keep that unit testing crap back in the 90s where it belongs. Biggest waste of time. It is just something to bring up so that you can look important, but does absolutely nothing in most cases. We have something called an IDE these days, we aren't programming by console or in notepad anymore. We know our code is correct because we can cursor over text and see the values. Keep unit testing in the past with all the other old timers.

Comment: @portfoliobuilder Yeah, mousing over values within your IDE will really help improve code quality. Because the state will always be the same, and the code will never change. Right on! And good luck.

Comment: @portfoliobuilder - you forgot /s

Answer (score 117, accepted):

In my experience, there are a couple of factors involved in this:

1. Management doesn't really understand what unit testing really is, or why it has real intrinsic value to them.
2. Management tends to be more concerned with rapid product delivery, and (incorrectly) sees unit testing as counterproductive to that goal.
3. There's a misperception that testing belongs solely in the pervue of QA. Developers are coders, and can't write tests.
4. There's a common misperception that management will have to spend money to do unit testing correctly, despite the fact that the tools are freely available. (There is, of course, the developer ramp up time to consider, but it's not really prohibitive.)
5. Will's answer will round this answer out: It's very hard to determine the value of test code (edit jcollum)

Naturally, there are other factors, but those are just what I've run into so far.

Comment: Yea, pretty much described my management and we have no testing.

Comment: And support for it in some popular langauges (C/C++) is poor.

Comment: @mgb - CxxUnit works pretty well for me...

Comment: CxxTest is very good as well.  Due to the poor reflection mechanisms in C++, it seems there are more varied "solutions" presented; CxxTest requires a preprocess step in the build system, whereas tools like TUT are entirely compile-time and language-supported, but awkward to use.

Comment: Coders rarely manage and managers rarely code.

Comment: I have found that users on stackoverflow.com tends to blame management for a lot of their problems like these. When I have asked my real-life friends about their 'management issues' that arise, usually I have found that they have never even voiced their concerns to management, must less embarked on a campaign to change people's viewpoints. Instead of saying 'management doesn't...' I try and think of ways I can help management see my point of view, and convince them my position is correct. I think this is a problem because developers aren't good at selling unit test.

Answer (score 88):

1) It's hard
2) It takes time
3) It's very hard to determine the value of test code

Point 3 is a sticky one.  Good unit tests reduce bugs.  But so does good production code.  How do you determine how many bugs don't exist because of your unit tests?  You can't measure what does not exist.  You can point to studies, but they don't fit nicely on your business manager's spreadsheet.

Comment: "Good unit tests reduce bugs. But so does good production code." -- Good unit tests make it possible to improve the production code. Even if the code is at first bad, but you have good test coverage, you can confidently refactor the system until the code is good.

Comment: Esko, in addition to having good coverage, you also have to have good tests that actually test something.  You could have 100% code coverage and actually be testing very little

Comment: Excellent answer! You've said the same thing as my answer in far fewer words.

Comment: Yes, unit tests take time. But so does "random bug fixing". Proper test driven development has "all" features "documented" in tests. If the tests are green, the product works as intended (except for usability issues etc). My experience is that the total development time is almost not affected at all. You spend more time on things, and get them right the first time around rather than after time spent on bug fixing.

Comment: And quite a few of the studies shows that unit testing has negative value. So showing studies is very inconclusive and should therefor yield some management resistance until it can be made likely that for the shop in question the value is positive

Comment: Quite a few of the studies? Can you cite some of these studies so we can pick them apart? I unit test everything I write, and I find tremendous value in my extremely meaningful tests.

Comment: In my experience, unit tests reduce number of bugs by a magnitude mostly by slowing down development speed by similar magnitude (3-4 times).

Comment: @KolA So if I get it right, for the same amount of time you get a proof that your code is valid, and a proof next development hasn't broke what exists currently ?

Comment: No. For the same amount of time I get 3-4 times more production code / features completed with the same amount of bugs per feature. This varies from dev to dev but usually bad developers also write bad tests and still make many mistakes so unit testing doesn't improve their code quality - only slows them down.
Tests never prove absence of bugs only their presence at best.

Comment: @KolA the slow down is just for initial delivery.  Not for overall development lifecycle of the feature.  There's a caveat, that you touched on.  If the developers stink, they write bad tests.  They also _over-test_.  I'm a huge supporter of TDD but I've seen things that are nuts, like a huge set of tests that seem only to test that mocks exist.  Don't let the failure to execute a strategy kill the strategy.  There's a lot of bad developers, writing a lot of bad advice.  I hope you get (or have had!) the opportunity to work on a CI/CD TDD centric team that actually knows how to do it.

Comment: @ocodo thanks. I've had worked with successful teams that use tests and they all write tests in very strict moderation carefully evaluating potential ROI for every test. So like everywhere in life the trick is to find the balance, but between two exteremes, no-tests-at-all vs test-all-religiously I will still pick former without any doubt

Comment: That's absolutely how to do it

Answer (score 74):

It is easy to put all the blame on “management.” But is management *really* telling you to specifically *not* do any unit testing?

Management in general does not (and probably should not) tell you how to do your job, whether it is modularization, abstract data types, design patterns, or unit testing. These are tools of trade that a successful, competent software engineer applies, but a poor engineer does not.

I think the real answer to your question is: unit testing is really difficult, and computer-science students are not trained for it.

It's easy when you are writing your own string class. When you are testing a real-life product, you run into challenges that nobody told you about in the powerpoint slides:

- User interaction. Half of your application is the user interface logic. How do you test it in an automated way, that doesn't break down if you move a button?
- Interaction with external APIs and frameworks. If you are writing a Windows kernel driver, how do you unit test it? Do you write stubs for every IRP and kernel function that you use, effectively creating a simulation of the OS kernel?
- Network communications is the thing of the 21st century. How do you coordinate a unit test consisting of several distributed components?
- How do you choose good test cases? I commonly see people trying the “do random things in a loop of 1000 iterations and see if it breaks” approach. When you do this the effort is higher than the returns, important bugs are missed, and unit testing is abandoned.
- How do you test that performance requirements are met?
- Knowledge of patterns in testing is scarce: stubs, canned responses, regression testing are concepts most people don't know. How many in your work place actually read a book about unit testing?

The one thing that we can blame management for is that requirement specifications rarely contain any requirements on quality level of the deliverable.

The next time your boss asks you to do a time estimate, include the time for writing a unit test and see what happens.

Comment: Good idea. But don't call out the time to create unit tests as separate from the time to create the "product" code!

Comment: Reading this answer made me realise that, While I'm familiar with the concept and the basics of unit testing, I really don't know how to do it effectively at all. Can you reccomend a good book on the subject?

Comment: Management doesn't specifically say "don't unit test," but they do hound you and ask for progress reports on cranking out features.  Sometimes they are not willing to listen to all the progress you made on unit tests.  Just an observation.

Comment: On one kernel driver that I worked on, I refactored a bunch of code into a library that I linked into a user-mode test harness. This particular code was environment-agnostic, so it was easy enough.

I haven't tried it, but IRPs, like filesystems and databases, should be mockable.

Comment: With Bochs or QEMU it is possible to write a simulation of your device for your kernel driver to speak with.

Comment: @Breton - Check out The Art of Unit Testing by Roy Osherove

Comment: @floding, fascinating answer. I think I'll have to go read a book on unit testing.

Comment: Effective Unit Testing by Lasse Koskela is good. Specification by Example by Gojko Adzic is also a good one.

Comment: Superb !! An eye opener for us...you said it well "Management in general does not (and probably should not) tell you how to do your job, whether it is modularization, abstract data types, design patterns, or unit testing."...I really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: YES YES YES a thousand times YES! We need to take responsibility for our own code and use unit tests as a tool for us to exercise the code we write. I've seen far too many people write code, then test via the application layer or even write a console application to simulate certain scenarios. 

It's bogus to let someone else take a tool away from you. Management doesn't take a level away from a carpenter because it takes time to make sure things aren't slanted.

Comment: @Breton, I recommend the book Growing Object-Oriented Software, Guided by Tests by Steve Freeman and Nat Pryce. It is a great resource to learn both TDD and OO.

Comment: The next time your boss asks you to do a time estimate, include the time for writing a unit test and see what happens.
What happens is your estimate increases by 2-3 times for a typical task (let's admit it that it does) and boss has a valid question "why".

Answer (score 27):

Most tests don't test anything.
You write a fileopen() function and a unittest that fails if the file doesn't exist and succeeds if the file does exist.
Great! Now did you check if it works with the filename in BIG5 chinese? on an NFS share?  on vista with the file on a USB key and UAC turned ON?

The problem is that the unit tests are written by the same programmer who wrote the function, to the same set of assumptions and with the same level of skill.
To really work the tests must be written by someone else, only to the published specs without them seeing the code. - In most companies just getting written specs would be a breakthrough!

Unit tests check for errors in the code of individual functions. They can work for data access layers, maths libraries etc where the inputs/outputs are well known and the internal structure is complex but for a lot of cases they are just a waste of time.
They fail when the errors are due to interactions between different parts of code or with the OS and the user. Problems like high/low DPI settings messing up a dialog box or a foreign language setting swapping a '.' and ',' aren't usually found.

Comment: I think this answer misses the mark a bit. Unit testing and functional testing are not, and should not be, the same thing.

Comment: An element you are missing is that unit tests are not just a one-and-done thing.  If I find out later that I need to fix a bug with fileopen() on an NFS share, then I can add a test to my test suite for this.  Then, when I do more development in the future I have regression testing in place.

Comment: Many errors come form interactions outside the code that the programmers hasn't thought of and can't be found by simply checking the code. A common gui problem is machines with very high/low DPI settings - you can unit test the dialog function all you like but won't spot this.

Comment: that's not the function of a unit test though, and interaction between different parts of code is very unit-testable and indeed, if those parts are being written by separate teams, unit testing your code against a shared interface and mocking the other team's component are good practices.

Comment: TDD handles the rigged test issue of "the programmer that wrote the code also then writes the tests" by making you write the tests before you write the code.

Comment: I think that makes it worse - you have a set of assumptions, you code those into the test then write a function that matches that test/assumptions.

Comment: @Martin Beckett (I know I'm a year late to the party): yes, you code in a circle from your assumptions to your assumptions. But that does seem at least minimally helpful because as your code changes, you must always line up assumptions (axioms) with assumptions (unit tests). I think that being forced to draw that line could help.

Answer (score 15):

There have been studies done on the ROI of unit tests - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237000/is-there-hard-evidence-of-the-roi-of-unit-testing).

Answer (score 15):

I've found a lot of developers who aren't interested in unit testing.  It always seems like a lot of work with little payoff when you start.  No one wants to sign up for extra work and so they resist.  Once people start, they usually enthusiastically stick with it, but getting them started can be hard.

Answer (score 12):

Aside from the issue of adoption of unit testing, unit testing isn't always worthwhile, though in general I think it is, when applied properly. There is nothing special about unit tests that saves them from being vulnerable to poor construction.

Unit tests have costs (creation, maintenance, and running) and are only worthwhile if they provide greater benefits than those costs. Test creation is a skill like any other, it requires specific experience and knowledge for success. Without sufficient experience it's very easy for even otherwise experienced developers to create low quality, low value, and/or high cost unit tests which are not worthwhile. Especially so given how difficult it can be to judge the value of a unit test.

Additionally, unit testing is just one way to improve code quality, but it's not the only way. In some circumstances and with some teams it may not be the most effective way to increase the quality of software.

Keep in mind that putting a lot of effort into unit testing is no guarantee of quality software. And, too, it is possible to produce software of the highest quality without any unit testing whatsoever.

Comment: What you are saying is true in statically typed languages.  In dynamically typed languages they are absolutely critical.  I mean your code is almost guaranteed to be crap without the tests.  I find this to be a large part of why some people seem to value unit tests so highly.

Answer (score 11):

There are plenty of companies out there that really do nothing along the lines of best practices.  No code reviews, no unit testing, no testing plans, no nothing, just by the seat of their pants.

Take this as an opportunity to get them to use a Continuous Integration platform and develop unit tests!  Easy way to impress the powers that be and increase the quality and stability of your code at the same time

Edit: As for reason, I think they just plain aren't aware of the current tools out there that make CI and unit testing extraordinarily easy.

Comment: I'm typically in a position where I have zero influence over policy decisions like these; I'm junior senator being overruled by committee chairs.

Comment: It takes a few minutes to start Hudson and write unit tests.  If unit tests are already on your "TODO" list, then you're just doing your job.  Committees are often impressed by fancy charts and images, so show them some pretty trend graphs from Hudson;)

Comment: Yeah!  Let's hear it for the truth. Despite all the time we developers spend banging on about best practice, it's not always used in the real world. Pity really.

Comment: Doctors don't ask if they should wash their hands do they?

Answer (score 11):

Well, my company hasn't gone with TDD or Unit Testing. To be honest, we're not sure how to do it. We can obviously do it for stupid functions like CapitalizeString(), etc, but we don't know how to do it for highly complex systems with complicated objects. Moreover, most of the people interviewed have either zero experience, or limited experience. It appears that Unit Testing is big from the SO crowd, but not particularly big in the available workpool.

TDD is a separate topic. We are morally opposed to TDD. We aren't cowboy coders, but we do believe that it stunts creativity and flexibility in a project. Moreover, having the coder who wrote the unit testing function makes no sense. When I do something, I code to all of the edge cases I can think of. What I need is another brain to look for things I might have missed. We don't have that. The teams are small and self-contained.

In short, we don't believe in TDD, but we would like to Unit Test. We just don't have the experience to do so, and we can't find it easily.

Comment: Back when the place I work had enough coders for it, we did pair programming.  I found it very effective for one to write tests as the other coded.  It led to very intelligent questions about the code, too.

Comment: The point to TDD, which you seem to be missing, is that you write all of the edge cases into your unit test. For each case, you write an assertion in your unit test. Then, if your actual code fails an assertion, you know that your code has a bug in it, and you've implemented your logic incorrectly. Since units are small, and your assertion tests specific code in the unit, it should be easy to pinpoint where your logic error is. The important thing is that you write your assertions first. Then make your code pass. Can you point out where this process stunts anything but bug-growth?

Comment: To try and unit test without writing the tests first will be very difficult. This is because your code will be hard to get into a test harness retrospectively. This is one of the main benefits of test first: the design is testable from the start because tests drove the design.

Comment: How can it be that you're "not sure how" to unit test but believe that TDD stunts creativity and flexibility?

Comment: @Steve 6 years on, it would be nice to know if you ever introduced unit testing (or even TDD) and whether you kept going with it.

Comment: 11 years on... ?

Answer (score 6):

Unit testing should be just a natural part of the code development workflow, just as the compiler is.

However, this requires educating the management on the benefits of the unit testing. Junior developers have relatively low chances to have such influence, though. Thus, whether a company is a proponent of the unit testing depends on whether they have a senior developer or architect that is an advocate of unit testing.

I believe this is the answer to your question **"what's missing and why aren't more companies doing unit testing"**. :-)

Comment: +1 for "should be a natural part of the code development workflow". Every *professional* developer should be doing there own *unit* testing regardless of official process. The only legitimate argument on this issue is the definition of a *unit*.

Comment: @Dunk If you don't define "unit" then you're only saying that "professional developers should be doing their own testing".

Comment: @ChrisW - Yes, professional developers should be doing their own testing. There is no reason for a developer to ever turn in code that they have not tested enough to feel confident that it works correctly. Unfortunately, this appears to be too much to ask of many developers.

Comment: When I say the definition of a unit is a legitimate argument, I am talking about the granularity of a unit. Is it a class? Is it a collection of classes? Is it a component? I think class level unit testing (with some exceptions) costs more than it benefits and leads to many meaningless tests...

Comment: which others have pointed out in this thread. Whereas, if one defines a collection of classes that work together as a unit then you can still do automated testing and your tests are generally more meaningful because they can focus more on higher level required functionality.

Comment: good point about compiler. I would rephrase answer though: most of unit tests are inferior substitute of strong typing features that popular compilers lack.

Answer (score 6):

From what I've seen, a lot of companies have huge, highly-coupled code bases that aren't practically unit testable. They also don't have decent testable requirements, so the unit tests would test against "as built" de facto requirements.

Comment: This deserves more upvotes.  Code which was designed through the principle of "what's design" / "Just do it!!" resulting in a big-ball-of-mud will have no separation / modularity (i.e. _units_) therefore it is _resistant to unit-testing_.  One of the benefits of testing first is that modularity becomes automatic.  One of the disastrous consequences of no tests is that it will likely become impossible to test the code in the future.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think laziness is the root cause of bad unit testing.  For my company, time constraints and "just get it done" attitude are the biggest deterrents for doing unit testing.  Also, the places where our systems fail tend to be more at the integration level (services, database accesses, complex queries that require specific data for testing), not the "unit level."  These things are just harder to test, and if you barely have enough time to get the feature done, you're probably not going to have time to get any useful tests done at the same time.

Comment: This is common. I think the argument is that if you think you'll ever change it in the future then you should have a test that makes sure it's working after it changes.

Answer (score 5):

Its probably a combination of a couple of things you mentioned already. Its difficult to measure cost savings of TDD. If you want to outsource your IT, you can show how much you pay per year for the guys you have on staff vs. the cost of contracting it out; its very concrete. How do you say, "Oh, this test caught a bug which would have taken me 4 hours to debug and fix..."?

Comment: How on earth can you guess how long a bug would take to debug and fix. Generally debugging is more random than that in my experience - I happen to have an idea where the problem is or I don't.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said its so hard to quantify the benefits of testing.

Answer (score 5):

The reason some places don't use it is simply because it takes a lot of work both to get started and to continue.  The fact that writing unit tests takes about as much time as writing the actual functionality seems to some managers like you're cutting your developer's productivity in half.

On top of that, you build team (or someone) needs to put the infrastructure in place and maintain it.

And as [Alan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557764/if-unit-testing-is-so-great-why-arent-more-companies-doing-it/557781#557781) says, a lot of places simply don't use best practices - they just want to see something tangible.

Answer (score 5):

I think that the programmer has to just start doing it.  A few simple tests to start with are easy to justify as part of development.

Something like a unit test is almost always necessary to get fast debugging turn around.  Just explain how much faster it is to launch the test than it is to arrange the correct input, set a debugger breakpoint, launch the application, etc.

Document the test in your code.  Just put a comment explaining where the test is and how to run it.  Future programmers will see it and hopefully the testing will spread!

Answer (score 4):

Unit testing is one of those black box terms that most people have heard, but don't know what exactly constitutes a unit test, where to start, how to write them, how to actually run tests, what exactly they should be testing, etc. etc. etc.

In a lot of cases, its easier for the unsure developer to simply dismiss them as unnecessary or some icing that only "enterprise level developers" need.

Answer (score 3):

Of course, in the ideal world, you can not argue against having a unit test.

However, whether you write a unit test depends on a number of things:

- How the software will be used. If you were writing software for just yourself would you write unit tests? Probably not. If you were writing pre-packaged software to be sold commercially, probably yes.
- How many people maintain the code....if it's just you, then you may know it well enough to be confident enough after making a change that a quick run through of the code is sufficient to ensure nothing has broken. If other people who did not originally write the code  must now maintain it then a unit test will help give them confidence that when they update the code to fix a big (that was obviously not captured in the unit test!) they have not broken anything.
- code complexity: only test code which needs a test. A one line variable assignment method does not need testing. A 50 line method with multiple paths of execution probably does.
- Practical commercial commercial considerations: The fact is writing unit tests does take longer than not doing so. If you are writing prototype software, that has an uncertain commercial future, then there is a pay off to be has between having code quickly, now, that works sufficiently well versus having unit tested code in 2 weeks that works better. Sometimes it pays to find out quickly (consumer appetite) if software will have a short shelf like and move on to the next project.

and as others have pointed out, a test is only as good as the person that wrote it.

Answer (score 3):

The main reason is that many developers and development managers don't have a clue that unit tests exist, or how to use them.

The second reason is that unit tests can only be used (in a sensible manner) with code that already fulfills some quality standards. Chances are, that some existing codebase doesn't fall into that category.

The third reason is lazyness and/or cheapness.

Answer (score 3):

Because unit tests are only usefull if you write testable code. And writing testable code is hard. And people are lazy and / or cheap.

EDIT : nuanced "lazy" as "lazy and / or cheap" ; some rare times, people actually have the skill and capacity and will to write tests, but they have something else to do that more directly affects the bottom line.

Comment: I'd upvote this, except I don't think people 'are lazy'. Think 'programming', ie 'your popular programming language and related tools, docs, training, workflows, stuff' was never designed in a way that would ease writing testable code. So to write testable code, you always have to go an extra mile. For no reward 'since it already works' by that point (so that writing tests first, code later, TDD, makes practical sense). Think this is more of a **cognitive bias** that tricks not only current programmers, but already tricked the authors of the 'programming' tools which the coders now build upon.

Comment: Yes, sure, sometimes people are cheap / broke / have better things to do (or as we put it politely "have trade offs to make.") Edited to reflect that. (I was about to jockingly add that, besides, most code is useless, so testing it is useless, too ; but that's just lack of sleep talking ;) )

Answer (score 3):

I'm a huge fan of unit tests and I also am a partner in a company doing contract development projects for various client types. In a month we'll touch 3-4 different projects of varying sizes.

If a project seems like it's going to be a one off, I'm not going to invest heavily in unit testing because that unit testing doesn't pay off for my business. On those types of projects I'm going to unit test things that I'm uncertain/unfamiliar with or that could change frequently (such as a parser for a data source I don't control.)

Whereas if I'm building something that I know is going to have a long life time, is a larger piece of work, that I'll be working with through multiple iterations, or will have a large impact on my clients if an error occurs, I'm going to invest in more unit testing. Again priority of tests revolves around uncertain/unfamiliar/changing code.

I think unit tests ought to revolve around the complexity of a task, as well as whether they're going to pay off. There's no sense in writing extra code that isn't going to get used.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience it really depends on the software you are writing. I have found it is extremely hard to write unit tests for a UI. I only use unit tests for portions of the system that have a definite in/out.

Comment: I agree.  If you use model/view/controller it makes a lot of sense to unit test the model and the controller.  UI is almost always best tested by a human.

Comment: Component tests are the UI equivalent of unit tests.  There can also be unit-tests of "business logic" that's used by the UI. Business logic in this sense is usually presentation logic.  Where UI testing and unit testing aren't compatible is in the area of rendering and testing the rendered output.  e.g. how am I gonna unit-test this QR code generator or this Pie chart?  The answer is, most certainly, you aren't going to unit test that.  Snapshot testing can give you regression testing value in those cases.

Answer (score 2):

> I miss unit testing -- it just makes life easier.

That is *not*, really, a sufficient reason for a company to adopt unit testing.

A sufficient reason might be "cheaper" (and/or, "better"): which is not as easy to prove about unit testing.

The only good reason might be "writing unit tests is the best use of developers' time", which is really hard to prove IMO: and it may be true in some places, for some software, with some developers, and not true elsewhere.

There are plenty of developers who don't think the world of unit tests: including some who think that other forms of testing (e.g. automated integration/functional tests) may be cheaper and more valuable, for example [Am I the only dev who doesn't like unit tests?](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?joel.3.725817.37)

Answer (score 2):

People are lazy and only adopt change when forced to.

Answer (score 2):

Like most good ideas, adoption has more to do with organizational path dependence than with the quality of idea.

In most companies that have shipped products, a substantial QA division has been created with a senior level QA head. Testing is the fiefdom of the QA team.

The QA team is unlikely to write unit test code because the company typically doesn't staff the QA team with its heavy duty coders.

The programming team is reluctant to write test code because it creates a conflict with the QA team.

I've been seeing more interest and  adoption of Unit Testing in groups where QA hasn't been spun off into a separate job function

Answer (score 2):

I think part of the problem is that developers are expecting business people to have the same set of values and to really care about the answer to "should we unit test or not?". We don't get approval beforehand from the business to use a high-level language rather than assembly language -- it's just usually the sensible way to get the work done.

The point is, *we* are the only ones qualified to make the call (which isn't to say that all of us have the same knowledge on the topic). Furthermore, even if your team doesn't, as a matter of policy, do unit testing (or name-your-method-of-the-day) it generally doesn't mean that *you* can't do it.

The truth is, we can't really prove ROI on most of the stuff we do at too fine of a granularity. Why unit testing is held up to this unreasonable/non-typical standard of proof is beyond me...

Comment: You do need management involved, however, because you have to get your co-developers on board and the best way for that to happen is for it to be a requirement from the top down.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sell everyone on testing do the following:

1. Write a bunch of tests.
2. Notify the other developers who change code and fail your test(s).
3. They'll fix their code.
4. Now you can release without those particular bugs.

Even a manager could understand this.

Comment: Unit testing won't cause your release to be bug-free.  It may reduce the bug count, but it's awfully hard to measure the number of bugs that /didn't/ hit production because of testing.

Comment: I don't know that management would be happy with someone writing a bunch of tests when they could be coding new functions. If they aren't on board with TDD you're likely to get in trouble for writing tests to cover code you didn't write.

Comment: @jcollum

As usual, it depends on the cost/profit ratio.

Answer (score 2):

My 2 cents:

- It requires some education and discipline, but new graduates already come with the proper knowledge.
- Tests overhead can be reduced with better tools and this is happening also (refactoring etc.)

**So, it's just a matter of time.**

There's the Martin-Coplien debate in which Bob Martin asserts that:

> "nowadays it is irresponsible for a developer to ship a line of code he has not executed in a unit test."

[http://www.infoq.com/interviews/coplien-martin-tdd]

Comment: I do not believe in the existence of a complex, real world system in which every single line of code was covered by unit tests.

Answer (score 2):

Companies are not performing unit testing, for the same reason that many websites are written poorly – ignorance, and people sticking to old habits.
At my company, since we started unit testing (with Nunit, and [Typemock](http://www.typemock.com)), we reach higher code coverage and release the software in a shorter time to market.

Answer (score 1):

Most companies are useless. Not the one that you (or I) work for, obviously.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Q: "Why aren't more companies doing [unit testing]?" A: "Because most companies are useless." Sounds like an answer to me...

Answer (score 1):

Two things are obstacles to unit testing

1. Everything new is hard to do
2. Everything that has no measurable profit, is bad.
3. Humans are lazy. Developers, indeed.

In my company (> 5.000 emp) unit tests "are there", but no chance to do TDD or get a big code coverage. It's to hard to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked for 3 companies so far, and have just recently started writing "offical" NUnit tests, and I have to say I'm a big fan. There are 2 points I've noticed however in the last few weeks:

1. It depends on the application - there are certain apps/pieces of an app that can be very easy to unit test. A function that does something basically the same each time, and produces an easily recognizable result. And there are sections that don't do this: a block of code that prints crystal reports or modifies an image - here the eyeball is actually needed and probably better/faster. These areas can discourage people from trying to write tests. They then just start thinking that if certain areas can't be unit tested, why bother?
2. The granularity of the test- many DEVs/QAs already have some sort of automation in place to 'test' a piece of functionality, and get confused as to how this is different from a unit test. Depending on their test, it might not be. The important thing here that takes some time to appreciate is that a good unit test is totally granular. It tests the minimum piece of logic that makes sense, which makes it repeatable, automatic, and hopefully always valid. It took me a little bit to really appreciate how useful that is, especially when you have a huge codebase and like to run regression tests after making a change to see if you just foobared the whole app.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's worthwhile to write a good unit test coverage for the code that you gonna be working with way into the future. For example, when you are working for a product company, by writing quality unit test cases you are simply making a time investment, knowing that all the hard work writing test cases will pay off and make your life easier down the line.

The sad truth is that a lot of software programmers work on in-house application development or contracting and just trying to get some software out the door. In those cases, the time investment does not make that much sense, as chances are you never see this pile of code ever again.

We can all argue that adhering to solid software development practices is responsibility of every developer. However, ROI means a lot to individual developers as it does to management.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to sound a little like an AA meeting.

I am a software engineer.

I was talking about software engineering to my brother at XMAS (he is a business analyst).

- He has been working as a BA for 10
  years.
- The conversation got around to
  testing.
- He had NEVER seen (or heard of) automatic unit
  testing.
- Or even heard of developers doing it.
- In that time he was worked for some of
  the big "alphabet" companies, on large government contracts.

So as far as I could tell, of the 100's of developers involved, none of them had heard of unit testing.

My predecessors in my current job used automatic validation tests, and had very few unit tests. Needless to say the code needs heavy refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main reason is simply that most managers and developers just don't care enough about quality. So they tend to believe that writing and automating unit tests is just too much effort (which it actually is) for little benefit.

Maybe there is not much we can do about the benefits, but we should be able to reduce the costs of creating and running tests by improving the relevant tools.

I find most current open source tools for developer testing to be quite primitive. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to exist much interest in the industry to improve this situation.

Comment: right. by the time *'those unit tests would have come handy - I see!'*, by that time *'your product already works... well... sort of! if it weren't for this ugly bug that took weeks...'* - isn't it? also agree that the current tools can seem awkward and only able to ease 'trivial' situations - as off note, 'trivial' meaning anything that the speaker knows the solution already. and when it gots, well, 'non-trivial', the testing code gets buggy. and with a buggy testing code, you are screwed.

Answer (score 0):

Simple it cost money to write and update unit tests.  Most of companies previous software doesn't have unit tests and will cost too much to write.  So they do not do it and it adds time to the development process so they also do not add it to new features.

Comment: You should read the links about ROI.

Answer (score 0):

I know one person who will look at a form with a single button and say "That's overkill, this should have a command line interface, so it can be automated in a script" and yet he never really got behind unit tests. I just don't get it. Fear of change could be part of it, but I've offered to walk him through the process and he's declined.

Obviously my current company doesn't enforce them, I've just taken it upon myself to write them when possible. I have found that setting up tests up front leads to witting better/cleaner code, because in thinking how to test something you generally have to consider it's later usage.

Answer (score 0):

The unit testing is great (easy to implement, easy to determinate that you have wrote enough test examples) when you have some code that operates as a server.

Example 1: You should mark in database posts that have 3 or more site moderator reviews 
What are tests variants

- check post without comments -> expect no marks
- check post with one comment -> expect no marks
- check post with 3 comments by common users -> expect no marks
- check post with 3 comments by common users and at least 1 comment by moderator -> expect no marks
- check post with 3 comments by common users and at least 3 comments by moderator -> expect mark for this post

explicit?

Example 2: You have a web site page that output the list of posts

How we should check that this list is misaligned in some browser?
How we should check that this list is colored properly and we didn't crush styles?

there is no easy solution to automate this

so the task during unit test creation is to understand - can you put code in server operation mode - if you can create test, if not then break to pieces and create test for the pieces or test manually.

And one more thing - the economy of unit testing you will get if you have more than 10-12 testing stages without significant code modification.

Regards,
Pavel